# Use Parameterised Dataset Filename in Dataflow Sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow that has a parameterised dataset that I'm using for the Sink activity. In the dataset it has a parameter that I've configured to be used as the filename.

[image: Dataset with the parameter]

[image: Parameters on the Dataset in question]

In the Dataflow sink activity "Settings" what "File name option" should I be using to call the filename I've specified in the Dataflow settings here:

[image]

If I set the "Filename option" to "Output to single file" then leave the field "Output to single file" empty, it fails.

If I set the "Filename option" to "Default" it doesn't work wither.

If I set it to "Output single file" and specify "@dataset().Filename" it doesn't work

Even the "$OutFileName" I've tried in the screengrab doesn't work. How can I call the parameter from the dataset?

[image: Sink output settings]

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Default` Filename Option always generates a sink file with random name by Azure data factory for Dataflows.

- Instead, you can use Filename Option as `Output to Single file` and specify the required filename in the pipeline. The following is a demonstration of the same.
- Create a dataflow parameter named `filename` of string.
  [image: Ref1]
- Go to sink settings, for `File Name` give the value as `$filename` (open expression builder, select the filename parameter)
  [image]
- Now publish this dataflow. Create a `dataflow` pipeline activity and select your dataflow. In the `Parameters` tab, the dataflow parameter `filename` appears. Give your desired value.

[image]

- When you run the pipeline, it successfully creates and the file will be created in the desired location. The following is the result of my demonstration.

[image]

Comment: The main thing is to configure the Dataflow to use the parameter from the Sink dataset for the output filename, rather than hard code the filename elsewhere.

Comment: hi @MattOwen, do you want to hardcode the filename value within dataflow and not pass it from pipeline?

Comment: @MattOwen dataset parameter can't be passed to dataflow, rather pipeline parameter can be used inside dataflow, similar to answer provided here.  
Also remember filename provided in dataflow overrides filename in dataset.